# Base64 decoding python help in socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, client, server

While implementing client-server UDP communication in python 3.4.2,got struck at the point to decode base64 encoded number sent from client to server.

**Client code:**

```
x = 10
y = 15
z = x + y
print("z value ",z) 
encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes(str(z), 'ascii'))
print('encoded z', encoded)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, #Internet 
                    socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #UDP

sock.sendto(encoded, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

**Server:**

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
while True:
   z, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) #buffer size is 1024 bytes
   decode = base64.b64decode(bytes(str(z),'ascii'))
   print("Received message:", z, decode)
   if not z:break
```

'Encoded value' at client side and 'z' value received at server side are same.
But struck at the line decode = base64.b64decode(bytes(str(z),'ascii')) on 
how to decode and display the z value properly on server side ?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some extra work going on in your server. In the client, encoded is a base64 encoded byte string. That's what you send in to your socket, and that's what the server gets out; a base64 encoded byte string. Your code is fine, but you accidentally garbled the message up by modifying z. Here's your server code, corrected:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
while True:
  z, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) #buffer size is 1024 bytes
  decode = base64.b64decode(z)
  print("Received message:", z, decode)
  if not z:break
```